# Semaphore mechanism in shell scripting to stop identical alerts after an issue has been reported

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script that counts the number of warnings in a log and send out alert email if it crosses the threshold. Sometimes when an issue is reported and when the number of warnings exceed the threshold, it keeps on sending multiple alert emails ( regarding the same issue ). I would like to put in a semaphore mechanism so that it stops sending alert emails for an identical issue once it is reported

Comment: `semaphore mechanism` ? Just keep a list of already sent warnings. When a new issue comes up, check if it is in the list already sent. It is is, don't sent it. If it is not, sent it and add to the list already sent. There is no "semaphore machanism" here, where should it go? Please show your script, some example input data, some example output and what have you tried.

Comment: Requests for research and coding are off-topic. Please read [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) and [Help On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.